# startMonitoringForRegion is not sending to didEnterRegion or didExitRegion

Tags: ios, ios6, core-location, cllocation, clregion

I have a location based app, all though the region is correct the app never moves to `didEnterRegion` or `didExitRegion`

```
for (int x = 0; x <= [[[TaskStore sharedStore] allTasks]count]-1; x++)
{
    NSArray *tasks = [[TaskStore sharedStore] allTasks];
    Task *selectedTask = [tasks objectAtIndex:x];

    location.latitude  = selectedTask.locationCoord.coordinate.latitude;
    location.longitude = selectedTask.locationCoord.coordinate.longitude;
    NSString* desiriedLoc = [selectedTask locationName];


    CLRegion *region = [[CLRegion alloc] initCircularRegionWithCenter: location radius: 30.0 identifier: desiriedLoc];
    NSLog(@"Entered new Location in Region %@", region);

    [locManager startMonitoringForRegion:region];

}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{

    NSLog(@"didEnterRegion for %@",region.identifier);

    UIAlertView *alr=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Reminder didEnterRegion"
                                            message:region.identifier delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Ok",nil];

    [alr show];
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{
    NSLog(@"didExitRegion for %@",region.identifier);

    UIAlertView *alr=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Reminder didExitRegion" message:region.identifier delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Ok",nil];

    [alr show];
}
```

Here is a string print out from my location:

Entered new Location with the coordinates Latitude: 51.509980 Longitude: -0.133700

and here is a string print out from the region:

Entered new Location in Region (identifier London) <+51.50998000,-0.13370000> radius 30.00m

Comment: Can you post the code where you instantiate the CLLocationManager instance?

Answer (score 0):

As @verbumdei commented, the only way you will get the `-didEnterRegion` and `-didExitRegion` is to establish a `CLLocationManagerDelegate`. Set your view as the delegate and add those methods and you should see the update.

One thing to note, you are using a 30M radius, you will need to be quite approximate in your location if you want to trigger updates. This is fairly easy to do in the Simulator, but in real life usage (on device), 30M accuracy is a bit tougher. I would start with 100M and work your way down based on experience.

Answer (score 0):

If you start monitoring while staying in the target region, nothing triggered.
Because it's not really an "didEnterRegion" event.

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to be setting

```
    region.notifyOnEntry = YES;
    region.notifyOnExit = YES;
```

Without explicitly setting these properties, the specified events will not get fired.